# Building maven raises maven-plugin:0.0.16 error, A required class was missing

Tags: maven, maven-3

When I was building my project a weird error came up:

```
A required class was missing while executing com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.16:install-node-and-npm: org/slf4j/helpers/MarkerIgnoringBase
```

I don't know but is it related to maven new version?
Last night I updated to maven 3.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was SLF4J issue..
I changed frontend-maven-plugin version to 0.0.23 and everything is fine now.

```xml
<plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
      <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.23</version>
</plugin>
```